# <a> href attribute adding current page url to links built in Gravity Forms html field

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

in building a form in Gravity Forms we have placed some HTML blocks in the form that are only revealed when particular answers are given (for a personality quiz). A sample of html used in the form is as follows:

```
<table style="border: none;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 40%; text-align: center;">
            <img src="https://familytraveller.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Bobbis-Cools-ES-Palette-300x300.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 60%; padding: 0 0 0 30px;"><h3>You chose City Break: Bobbi’s Cools Eye Shadow Palette</h3>
        <p>Take along the ultimate eye shadow palette, designed by Bobbi Brown to make it easy for any woman to create endless standout eye looks.
<a href=“http://lhrt4.worlddutyfree.com/lhrt4_en/bobbi-brown-palette-2.html“><h3>Buy it here</h3></a></p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The link is not working as it should, although a full url is provided, and the source code shows the correct href attribute, the url of the page containing the link is appended to the url in the href. For example in this case the link leads to "https://familytraveller.com/travel-tips/summer-sunshine-beauty-quiz/http://lhrt4.worlddutyfree.com/lhrt4_en/bobbi-brown-palette-2.html" .

I cannot see why this is happening. How do I stop this from happening? Is it because the link is within a form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the double quote marks ("...") in the href attribute with single quote marks and this resolved the issue